# sharing sass variables with js ".sass files"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a problem with sharing sass variables with js, I am using Reactjs for my project and I want to share some sass variable related to breakpoints in order to build responsive components.
I saw that we can share variable using `:export{}` expression on `.scss` files I tried the same expression on `.sass` files but it does not work. Is there any equivalent syntax for `:eport{}` in `.sass` files?

Thanks

Comment: why not using css variables?

Comment: Is this of any use? --- https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-share-variables-between-js-and-sass

Comment: If I were you I would seek a solution that instead let you share js variables with sass.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I saw this solution but my issue is with `.sass` file not `.scss` the "indentation syntax". `:export{}` keyword not working on `.sass` files

Comment: @xianshenglu this will lead to none consistency on the file structure of the project, all file is .sass file and I do not want to use CSS directly

Comment: I'm sorry that site didn't have the solution you wanted. I thought that "Webpack module bundler" they highlight on the page was designed for these kinds of projects.

Comment: Apparently, underneath the textual exterior, sass and scss are identical, and therefore can import each other. So, an idea could be to convert sass to scss and then use the scss method. Here is a site that describes the process (supposedly) for exporting to react from scss. - Link is here -- https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript. 
  If this doesn't work, i'm sorry, it's the best I can do for now.

Comment: I thought css pre-processors was used to strengthen css instead of replacing.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest putting your variables in a JSON file and then you could import them to your SCSS files by setting-up [JSON Importer](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer).

Those same variables which were defined in the JSON file could be imported to any other JS files.

---

Regardless to that, I can also suggest copying all the SCSS content to [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) files, and then you'll solve the problem of two separate world which are unable to communicate with each-other.

I have been working with styled-components (in React apps) with great success and am recommending this approach.

Comment: I dislike that tool you suggested, it requires you to format your JSON in a particular way (if you can't reliably use valid JSON what's the point?), instead look to https://github.com/sasstools/json-importer or my fork of the tool you recommended https://github.com/One-Nexus/sass-json-importer

Comment: @ESR - what do you mean format in a particular way? the README examples look like normal JSON. Anyway, the repos which you've suggested look very nice, thank you for adding it to the discussion

Comment: The compiler can break with valid JSON is what I'm saying - valid JSON should never break the compiler. Read the documentation for more info.